# How to download Wikipedia articles' content?

Tags: wikipedia

I have some analysis work with Wolfram Language. Which is why, I want to download a few Wikipedia articles' body (content). It can be random or some specific articles. But, I am not sure how it could be done. If anyone can provide any guidance/help it'll be really helpful.

Comment: data = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_G._Stork"]

Answer (score 2):

There are two helpful functions WikipediaData and WikipediaSearch. There are also the related functions WikidataData and WikidataSearch. There is also a ResourceFunction [ImportWikipediaTables](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ImportWikipediaTables/). Arnoud Buzing has also created a ResourceFunction [RandomWikipediaData](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomWikipediaData/).

Comment: thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the contents of a Wikipedia article; two popular methods are using [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and [`WikipediaData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WikipediaData.html), the latter being my suggestion as it "utilizes MediaWiki's API to retrieve article and category contents and metadata from Wikipedia" instead of scraping the raw content of the webpage like `Import` does.

Many properties and different usages are available to return different sets of data on the article.  As a basic example, let's look at (a snippet of) the plaintext content of the *Mathematica* article.

```
WikipediaData["Mathematica"] // Snippet[#, 9] &
```

> Wolfram Mathematica is a software system with built-in libraries for several
> areas of technical computing that allow machine learning, statistics, symbolic
> computation, data manipulation, network analysis, time series analysis, NLP,
> optimization, plotting functions and various types of data, implementation of
> algorithms, creation of user interfaces, and interfacing with programs written
> in other programming languages. It was conceived by Stephen Wolfram, and is
> developed by Wolfram Research of Champaign, Illinois. The Wolfram Language is
> the programming language used in Mathematica. Mathematica 1.0 was released on
> June 23, 1988 in Champaign, Illinois and Santa Clara, California.

Another usage is getting a list of the titles of articles that link to the *Mathematica* article.

```
WikipediaData["Mathematica", "BacklinksList"] // Short
```

> {3D Slicer,ADaMSoft,ADMB,Advanced Simulation Library,Algebrator,ALTRAN,Amira (software),<<308>>,X-13ARIMA-SEATS,XaoS,Xcas,XLfit,XLispStat,XploRe,Yacas}

`WikipediaData["RandomArticle"]` also produces *the title* of a random article; `WikipediaData@WikipediaData["RandomArticle"]` will return the plaintext content of a random article.